# iOS RSS reader with notification for items containing certain keywords

Tags: ios, rss

I am looking for an IOS app that allows me to set keywords on a global or feed basis. The app should show me a notification if there are any items that match one of the keywords. A match on the title should be sufficient, but matching the summary and title is even better. On Android, there is Palabre. Is there a similar app for IOS?

I found similar questions here, but all of them are quite old and the apps mentioned there are not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with the Pro Inoreader plan. Inoreader is not a standalone RSS reader. You have to create an account for the online service. The pro version (50$/year) let's you create "rules". Rules can act on all feeds, a folder, a feed. A rule can be build to say
- if a new item in all feeds/this folder/this feed contain this word, then send me a notification on my phone (through the mobile version of Inoreader).